# Iterating over Guava Mutlimaps

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

Is there a way to get a Key-Value pair of each element in a MultiMap in each iteration, without first adding them to a list?

I'd like to implement something like this:

(I know this will not work)

```
public class MutliMapTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    // Adding some key/value
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
    myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

    Iterator it = myMultimap.keySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
      String type = it.next().toString();
      String name = myMultimap.gettype); // This will get me a List, but I want a single element

      System.out.println("Iteration : " + type + " : " + name)
    }
 }
}
```

I'd like some output similar to:

```
Iteration : Fruits : Bannana
Iteration : Fruits : Apple
Iteration : Fruits : Pear
Iteration : Vegetables : Carrot
```

Comment: which multimap implementation are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    // Adding some key/value
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
    myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
    myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : myMultimap.entries()) {
        System.out.println("K : " + e.getKey() + " V : " + e.getValue());
    }

}
```

prints

```
K : Vegetables V : Carrot
K : Fruits V : Bannana
K : Fruits V : Apple
K : Fruits V : Pear
```

Comment: Thank you OldCurmudgeon. Perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the [`entries`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#entries%28%29) method does what you want

Assuming you are talking about the Google Guava variation of MultiMap

Answer (score 1):

A `Multimap` is a `Map` of key -> collection, and for such a class use nested foreach loops over the appropriate collections:

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultimap;

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : myMultimap.entrySet()) {
    for (String value ; entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out: a `Map` of key -> list is only _one_ way of thinking about a `Multimap`. Conceptually, a multimap a map in which there can be multiple mappings for the same key. Guava's `Multimap` API supports both ways of looking at it.

Comment: @col quite right. I've changed the answer to "collection" instead of "list". The code still applies as is.

Comment: I wasn't emphasizing the list vs. collection thing there, more the key -> collection way of looking at a multimap ("`a -> [1, 2], b -> [3]`") vs. the key -> value with multiple values per key allowed way of looking at it ("`a -> 1, a -> 2, b -> 3`"), as the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for `Multimap` mention.